# How to setup Postback URL in html page

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, asp.net

`I have a insurance website. When a visitor enter zipcode and click on "Get my Quote" button the result page will open.

Now i need code to trigger postback url once "Result page" is displayed.

Postback url: [https://xml.adnetwork.com/conversion?c={click_id}&value={value}](https://xml.adnetwork.com/conversion?c=%7Bclick_id%7D&value=%7Bvalue%7D)

Zipcode form code:

[ZIPcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu2dM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlYdf.png)

I am not understanding how to setup this. I need you guys to help me with a code so that once get my quote button is clicked postback url should trigger.
[FORM CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIiuf.png)

Comment: As per [ask] please provide any code as text rather than pictures.

Comment: How does this relate to php or asp.net? I see no code from either of those platforms. And no jquery either. Please only tag whats actually relevant to your situation

Comment: And what's your actual question? Are you asking how to send a http request to that URL using code? You can easily Google how to send a http request using whatever programming question you choose. I doubt we need to repeat that information again here. Or did you have a more specific question? Have you actually researched or tried anything yourself so far? What issue are you facing exactly, based on your efforts? We can help you where needed but we are not here to entirely replace your own attempts to figure this out, especially when it seems to be about a very common researchable process

Comment: P.s. your html seems to be invalid due to nested and/or incomplete form tags. Pay closer attention  and check your code more carefully.

Comment: Sir,   I just need postback url should trigger when Get my Quote button is clicked.  And this is html page. I tried many javascript codes searching google but no success.

Comment: Well, what does "no success" actually mean, specifically? Show us what you tried and explain what went wrong,  including showing any error messages or unexpected results that you didnt understand. That's how this site works. You can [edit] your question. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Result Page</title>
    <script>
        // Function to get URL parameter by name
        function getParameterByName(name, url) {
            if (!url) url = window.location.href;
            name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
            var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
                results = regex.exec(url);
            if (!results) return null;
            if (!results[2]) return '';
            return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }

        window.onload = function() {
            // Get click ID and value from URL
            var clickId = getParameterByName('click_id');
            var value = getParameterByName('value');

            // Construct postback URL
            var postbackURL = `https://xml.adnetwork.com/conversion?c=${clickId}&value=${value}`;

            // Trigger postback by creating an image element with the postback URL as the source
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = postbackURL;
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Your result page content goes here -->
    <h1>Result Page</h1>
    <!-- Other content -->

    <script>
        // Other JavaScript logic specific to your result page can be added here
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In what way does this solve the problem? Please explain your code. See also [answer]. A random code dump without context has no value to anyone

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).